# Adding | pipe to the end of text printed with python in CMD prompt

Tags: python, cmd

[image]I'm not sure if title is making any sense or not, so here's a visual.
Screenshot of CMD prompt

On left: What I'm trying to achieve.

On right: Current progress.

I'm able to add | pip in the beginning, but..
How do I add | pipe at the end of text?

code;;

```
def menu():
    print("\n ", end="") ## new line and a single space offset
    print("_"*40)
    print("|", end="") ##end, ends the str right there.
    print("\n|", end="")

    print("\t[1] Opt1")
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[2] Opt2")
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[3] Opt3")
    print("|", end="")
    print("-"*40)
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[4] Opt4")
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[5] Opt5")
    print("|", end="")
    print("-"*40)
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[6] Opt6")
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[7] Opt7")
    print("|", end="")
    print("\t[8] Opt8")
    print("|", end="")

    print("\n|", end="")
    print("_"*40)
    print("\n ", end="") #a new line and a single space offset
    choice = input("\tEnter your choice in the keyboard[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]: ")

menu()
```

Comment: If it's not a challenge and you need this for further usage consider prettytable: https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Comment: That would be too much help for my school project. xD
I will try it in personal proj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `end` for print when you join print outputs with `end` value,
check my code, I think it will help you

my functions:

- `print_line`: print a line `|----|`
- `print_option`: print a option line

```py
def print_line():
    print("|", end="")
    print("_"*39, end="")
    print("|")

def print_option(option):
    message = "\t"+option
    print("|", end="")
    print(message, end="")
    print(" "*(40-(len(option)+8)), end="")
    print("|")

def menu():
    print_line()
    print_option("[1] Opt1")
    print_option("[2] Opt2")
    print_option("[3] Opt3")
    print_line()
    print_option("[4] Opt4")
    print_option("[5] Opt5")
    print_line()
    print_option("[6] Opt6")
    print_option("[7] Opt7")
    print_option("[8] Opt8")
    print_line()
    choice = input("\tEnter your choice in the keyboard[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]: ")

menu()
```

output:

[image]